# LINQ Select from two Collections with same length

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, collections

```
var listA = new List<string> {"One", "Two", "Three"};
var listB = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
var listC = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
```

Here I've got two Lists with the same length. Is there a way to fill third `listC` with LINQ?

```
"One", 1
"Two", 2
"Three", 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking the [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var listA = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
var listB = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var listC = listA.Zip(listB, (s, i) => new Tuple<string, int>(s, i)).ToList();
```